# Android Stack management and bring older activities on top

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have activity A that starts activity B which starts activity C and this starts D

A -> B -> C -> D

When a user clicks on a button in activity D, i want to bring B to the top of the stack and take D & C completely out of the stack. But A shown be there in the stack and when user clicks back in B s/he should be directed to A. Is there a way to do this ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It is possible.

You should read [this topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ActivityB should be single top (Declaration in manifest) to avoid activity recreation.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed() to navigate to the desired activity without a hassle.